# Adding interaction to heat map to show another bokeh plot based on the selection

Tags: bokeh, heatmap

I'm trying to add interaction to heatmap(using rect) using CustomJS to show another bokeh plot based on the selected value. 
This is what I've tried

```
heat_map_df_stack = pd.DataFrame(heat_map_df.stack(), columns=['rate']).reset_index()
....
issue_heat_map = figure(title="",
       x_range=issues, y_range=list(reversed(products)),
       x_axis_location="above", plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
       tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='below',
       tooltips=[('Product & Issue Id', '@Product @Issue'), ('Issue Count', '@rate')],
       name='issue_heat_map')
....   

issue_heat_map.rect(x="Issue", y="Product", width=1, height=1,
   source=heat_map_df_stack,
   fill_color={'field': 'rate', 'transform': mapper},
   line_color=None)
....

taptool = issue_heat_map.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = ""), code =
"""
console.log('test')
console.log(cb_obj)
var inds = cb_obj.selected;
window.alert(inds);
""")
```

On click of the rect or selection, nothing is happening now.

[Edit] : I updated the above code. Now I'm able to see console log and alert, but have no clue on how to get selected value from the heat map.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using the bokeh server. The code is a adaption of the heatmap example from the bokeh [gallery](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/unemployment.html).

```
from math import pi
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper, BasicTicker, PrintfTickFormatter, ColorBar
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.sampledata.unemployment1948 import data

data['Year'] = data['Year'].astype(str)
data = data.set_index('Year')
data.drop('Annual', axis=1, inplace=True)
data.columns.name = 'Month'

years = list(data.index)
months = list(data.columns)

# reshape to 1D array or rates with a month and year for each row.
df = pd.DataFrame(data.stack(), columns=['rate']).reset_index()
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

# this is the colormap from the original NYTimes plot
colors = ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2", "#dfccce", "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"]
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=df.rate.min(), high=df.rate.max())

TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom, tap"

p = figure(title="US Unemployment ({0} - {1})".format(years[0], years[-1]),
           x_range=years, y_range=list(reversed(months)),
           x_axis_location="above", plot_width=900, plot_height=400,
           tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='below',
           tooltips=[('date', '@Month @Year'), ('rate', '@rate%')])

p.grid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.axis_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "5pt"
p.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi / 3

heatmap = p.rect(x="Year", y="Month", width=1, height=1,
       source=source,
       fill_color={'field': 'rate', 'transform': mapper},
       line_color=None)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, major_label_text_font_size="5pt",
                     ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=len(colors)),
                     formatter=PrintfTickFormatter(format="%d%%"),
                     label_standoff=6, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0))
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

# Adding the tap interaction + plot
other_source = ColumnDataSource({'x': range(10), 'y': range(10)})
other_plot = figure(title="Other Plot")
other_line = other_plot.line(x='x', y='y', source=other_source)


def update(attr, old, new):
    if not old:
        old = [1]
    if new:
        other_source.data.update(y=np.array(other_source.data['y'])/old[0]*new[0])


source.selected.on_change('indices', update)

curdoc().add_root(gridplot([[p, other_plot]]))
```

The important part are the last few lines, where I set up the second plot and add the update function to change the slope of the line in the second plot according to the selected rect from the heatmap.

Comment: I tried the above example but I'm getting 2018-10-16 11:25:25,220 error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): IndexError('list index out of range',)

Comment: The error should come from not checking the if the value of **old** is valid. For the case above

    `if not old:
        old = [1]`

should fix the problem by supplying a valid start value for old. Fixed it in the code above.